# In Haskell, are "higher-kinded types" *really* types? Or do they merely denote collections of *concrete* types and nothing more?

Tags: haskell, types, higher-kinded-types, parametric-polymorphism

#### Paramametrically polymorphic functions

Consider the following function:

```
f :: a -> Int
f x = (1 :: Int)
```

We might say that the type of `f` is `a -> Int`, and that `f` therefore is of a "polymorphic" type.

Which of the following is the most accurate way to think about `f`?

1. There is in fact a *single* `f` of type `a -> Int`. It can be used, however, as an `f :: Int -> Int`, as an `f :: Double -> Int`, and so forth.
2. Literally speaking, the type of `f` is NOT `a -> Int`. Indeed, that is just a shorthand way of saying that there is a *family* of functions `f` whose type is concrete (i.e., there is an `f :: Int -> Int`, an `f :: Double -> Double`, and so forth; moreover, each of these functions is distinct from each other).

#### Higher Kinded Types

Similarly, we can consider the following type declaration:

```
data Maybe a = Just a | Nothing
```

And ask which of the two views is more correct:

1. There is no *single* type `Maybe`; indeed, there is merely a family of concrete types (`Maybe Int`, `Maybe String`, etc) and nothing more.
2. There is *in fact* a single type `Maybe`. This type is a higher-kinded type. When we say that it is a "type" we mean it literally (not as a shorthand for (1)). It just so happens that we can also write `Maybe Int`, `Maybe Double`, and so forth to generate *distinct* types (which happen to be concrete). But, at the end of the day (i.e.): `Maybe`, `Maybe Int`, and `Maybe String` denote **three** distinct types, two of which are concrete and one of which is higher-kinded.

#### Question Summary

In Haskell, are "higher-kinded types" really types? Or are only concrete types "the real types", and when we speak of "higher-kinded types" we are merely denoting a *family* of concrete types. Moreover, do paramametrically polymorphic functions denote functions of a *single type*, or do they *merely* denote a *collection* functions of *concrete types* (and nothing more)?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's not entirely clear what you want to ask, and what is the practical difference between 1 and 2 in both cases, but from an underlying math perspective:

**Parametrically Polymorphic Functions**

`f` actually has type `f :: forall a.a->int`

It is a perfectly legal type for a function in typed lambda calculus, which Haskell is based on. It can be something like:

```
f = λa:Type.λx:a.(body for f)
```

How do you get `Double->Int` from it? You *apply* it to `Double` type:

```
f Double = (λa:Type.λx:a.(body for f)) Double => λx:Double.(body for f|a=Double)
```

Haskell does both operations (type abstraction and type application) behind the scene, although it is possible to explicitly state `forall` part in the type signature with `XExplicitForAll` GHC extension, and explicitly make a `Double->Int` instance of `f` with type signature:

```
f_double :: Double -> Int
f_double = f
```

**Higher Kinded Types**

Consider a simple type:

```
data Example = IntVal Int | NoVal
```

(Yes, it is `Maybe Int`).

`Maybe` is a *type* constructor, just like `IntVal` is a *data* constructor. It is exactly the same thing, only 'one level higher', in the sense that `Maybe` is applied to `Type`, much like `IntVal` is applied to `Int`.

In lambda calculus, `Maybe` has type:

```
Maybe : Type->Type
```

Haskell doesn't allow you to get a type from type constructor, but allows you to get a *kind* (which is just a fancy name for *type of type*):

```
:k Maybe
Maybe :: * -> *
```

So no, `Maybe` is not a *type*: you can't have an object with the type `Maybe`. `Maybe` is (almost) a function from types to types, like `IntVal` is a function from values to values.

We call the result of applying `Maybe` to `String` as `Maybe String`, like we call the result of applying `IntVal` to `4` as `IntVal 4`.

Comment: If `Maybe a` is not a type, then how can it be a member of the typeclass `Monad`? I thought, for example, it was not true to say that a concrete `Maybe` (say, `Maybe Int`) is a monad. Indeed, `Maybe Int` is *not* a monad, but `Maybe a` *is* a monad. 

So my question from your answer is this: what exactly are the members of type classes? Types? Type constructors?

Comment: Basically, your answer is making me realize that *types* are distinct from *type constructors* (even though they often have the same name). I'm realizing, I think, that type classes have as members not *types* but *type constructors*. Is that the case?

Comment: @George, Members of typeclasses are *things*. `:k Monad` tells that `Monad` expects `(*->*)` as its argument (and `Maybe` is exactly that *kind* of thing). But `:k Num`, for example, expects `*`, so `Maybe` can't be a member of `Num` (but `Maybe Int` can)

Comment: @George: (1) When we speak loosely, "type" means something like "everything that can only live on the right of `::`, possibly except for type classes/constraints"; when we speak precisely, "type" means "everything of kind `*`". (2) Type classes can contain types *or* type constructors *or* anything else!  `Eq` has kind `* -> Constraint`, but `Functor` has kind `(* -> *) -> Constraint`. People used to refer to things like `Functor` as "constructor classes" to distinguish them, but this usage has mostly fallen out of favor.  [cont…]

Comment: @George: […cont] And finally, (3) `Maybe a` is not a monad; `Maybe` is a monad. Only things of kind `* -> *` can be monads!  And `Maybe a` is of kind `*` (or it has a scope error, if `a` is not in scope.)

Comment: I would argue that it is often useful to *not* distinguish between types and type constructors unless there is a particularly good reason, for the same reason as not distinguishing between functions and (non-function) values. I would say this is especially the case when `PolyKinds` or (in GHC 8) `TypeInType` are in use. With `PolyKinds`, you can have `Proxy :: Proxy Int` as well as `Proxy :: Proxy []`. `TypeInType` removes the distinction between types and kinds, so `* -> *` itself becomes a type (since `* -> * :: *`, which you can see here: `Just 1 :: (Maybe :: ((* -> *) :: *)) Int`).

Answer (score 7):

First a question: Is the statement "all lists have length" a single statement or a series of statements "list1 has length", "list2 has length",...?

If you give the type of `f` with explicit `forall`, you get `f :: forall a. a -> Int`. First of all, this is not "higher-kinded". We can do the following in GHCI:

```
λ> :set -XRankNTypes
λ> :k (forall a. a -> Int)
(forall a. a -> Int) :: *
```

So `f` has a kind of `*`.

Now, in Haskell, we can use `~` for type equality. We can set the following to check stuff in GHCI:

```
λ> :set -XImpredicativeTypes
λ> :set -XTypeFamilies
λ> :t undefined :: ((~) Int Int) => a
undefined :: ((~) Int Int) => a :: a
```

This shows that GHC figured out type equality for this example. Type inequality will give the following error:

```
λ> undefined :: ((~) (Int -> Int) (Int)) => a

<interactive>:22:1:
    Couldn't match expected type ‘Int’ with actual type ‘Int -> Int’
    In the expression: undefined :: ((~) (Int -> Int) (Int)) => a
    In an equation for ‘it’:
    it = undefined :: ((~) (Int -> Int) (Int)) => a
```

Now using this method directly will prevent us from comparing the type of `f`, but I found a slight variant that should work for our purposes:

```
λ> :t undefined :: forall a. ((a -> Int) ~ (Int -> Int)) => a
undefined :: forall a. ((a -> Int) ~ (Int -> Int)) => a :: Int
```

In other words, if `f` is type-equivalent to `g :: Int -> Int`, then `a` must be Int. This is similar to `x = y`, `y = 0` so `x = 0`. We don't have `x = 0` until we specify `y = 0`, until then we just have `x = y`.

`Maybe` is different because it has the following kind:

```
λ> :k Maybe
Maybe :: * -> *
```

Because we're using `DataKinds`, we have `:k (~) :: k -> k -> GHC.Prim.Constraint`, so we can do things like:

```
λ> :t undefined :: (~) Maybe Maybe => Int
undefined :: (~) Maybe Maybe => Int :: Int

λ> :k Either ()
Either () :: * -> *

λ> :t undefined :: (~) Maybe (Either ()) => Int
Couldn't match expected type ‘Either ()’ with actual type ‘Maybe’
```

To sum up, `f :: forall a. a -> Int` makes as much sense as the statement "if you give me anything, I'll give you an Int". Could you translate the statement into a bunch of statements "if you give me a dog..", "if you give me a penny.."? Yeah, but it weakens the statement. At the end, decide precisely what you mean by the "same" and you get your answer.